# NodeJS, Mongoose - findOneAndUpdate not working from Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to NodeJS and MongoDB and Mongoose.

This works when I run it in a MongoDB client (see screenshot).

**Question** : What do I need to do differently to make the update work from the server-side code ?

```
db.getCollection('vouchers').findOneAndUpdate(
    {"lease":"71610b3209bb37a59c90b20c36d3bb34"}, 
    { $set: {'value':93} },
    { returnNewDocument: true }
)
```

[image]

However when I run the exact same code from my NodeJS server, using Mongoose, it does not perform the update.

```
var result = Voucher.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"lease":"71610b3209bb37a59c90b20c36d3bb34"}, 
    { 
        $set: {'value':92}
    },
    {
        returnNewDocument: true
    }
);
```

The result object looks like :

```
Query {  
_mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection: 
   NativeCollection {
     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
     opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
     name: 'vouchers',
     collectionName: 'vouchers',
     conn: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: undefined,
        pass: undefined,
        name: 'ellispark_db',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: false,
        db: [Object] },
     queue: [],
     buffer: false,
     emitter: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined } },
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        plugins: [Object] },
     modelName: 'Voucher',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: undefined,
        pass: undefined,
        name: 'ellispark_db',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: false,
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     _events: { init: [Function], save: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     schema: 
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [Object],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Object],
        s: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'vouchers',
        collectionName: 'vouchers',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     insertMany: [Function] },
  schema: 
   Schema {
     obj: 
      { msisdn: [Object],
        name: [Object],
        lease: [Object],
        description: [Object],
        bcodeRef: [Object],
        smsRef: [Object],
        subscriberRef: [Object],
        value: [Object] },
     paths: 
      { msisdn: [Object],
        name: [Object],
        lease: [Object],
        description: [Object],
        bcodeRef: [Object],
        smsRef: [Object],
        subscriberRef: [Object],
        value: [Object],
        _id: [Object],
        __v: [Object] },
     aliases: {},
     subpaths: {},
     virtuals: { id: [Object] },
     singleNestedPaths: {},
     nested: {},
     inherits: {},
     callQueue: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     _indexes: [],
     methods: {},
     statics: {},
     tree: 
      { msisdn: [Object],
        name: [Object],
        lease: [Object],
        description: [Object],
        bcodeRef: [Object],
        smsRef: [Object],
        subscriberRef: [Object],
        value: [Object],
        _id: [Object],
        __v: [Function: Number],
        id: [Object] },
     query: {},
     childSchemas: [],
     plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     s: { hooks: [Object], kareemHooks: [Object] },
     options: 
      { retainKeyOrder: false,
        typeKey: 'type',
        id: true,
        noVirtualId: false,
        _id: true,
        noId: false,
        validateBeforeSave: true,
        read: null,
        shardKey: null,
        autoIndex: null,
        minimize: true,
        discriminatorKey: '__t',
        versionKey: '__v',
        capped: false,
        bufferCommands: true,
        strict: true,
        pluralization: true },
     '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
  op: 'findOneAndUpdate',
  options: { retainKeyOrder: false, returnNewDocument: true },
  _conditions: { lease: '71610b3209bb37a59c90b20c36d3bb34' },
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: { '$set': { value: 92 } },
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: 
   NodeCollection {
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'vouchers',
        collectionName: 'vouchers',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     collectionName: 'vouchers' },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  _count: [Function],
  _execUpdate: [Function],
  _find: [Function],
  _findOne: [Function],
  _findOneAndRemove: [Function],
  _findOneAndUpdate: [Function],
  _replaceOne: [Function],
  _updateMany: [Function],
  _updateOne: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`findOneAndUpdate` is an asynchronous function. You need call a callback. In this callback you recive the results.

```
Voucher.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"lease":"71610b3209bb37a59c90b20c36d3bb34"}, 
    { 
        $set: {'value':92}
    },
    {
        returnNewDocument: true
    }
, function( error, result){
    // In this moment, you recive a result object or error

    // ... Your code when have result ... //
});
```

More info in mongoose website [documentation for findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: *facepalm* I found the answer in those docs just a few minutes after posting. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -2):

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        collection.findOneAndUpdate({ id: id }, { $set: product }, {
            returnNewDocument: true
        }).then(data => {
            console.log("Data", data);
            resolve(data);
        }, err => {
            console.log("Error Update in Index1", err);
            reject("Update User Failed");
        });
    });
```